# How to install IMageMagick and ImageWand on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, include, imagemagick

I tried to build ImageMagick lib from source, and set `ImageMagick_MagickWand_LIBRARY`,`ImageMagick_Magick++_LIBRARY`,`ImageMagick_MagickCore_LIBRARY` enveironemt variables in `~/.zshrc` to `/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand`,`/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++`,`/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickCore` accordingly. But I have following error:

```
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h:29:12: fatal error: 'MagickCore/magick-config.h' file not found
#  include "MagickCore/magick-config.h"
```

In my code it lloks like this:

```cpp
#include "ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h"
```

I have no idea why this error is present. can anyone help me?

Comment: Correct inclusion of the `MagickWand.h` header is `#include "MagickWand/MagickWand.h"` (**without** `ImageMagick-7` component). For make this inclusion work, you need to adjust include directories to contain `/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7`.

Comment: Instead of `-I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7` it's better to use `$(pkg-config --cflags MagickWand)` as compiler flag and `$(pkg-config --libs MagickWand)` as linker flag.